# How to install iOS 12 simulator in the Xcode 10 beta?

Tags: xcode10, ios12, macos-mojave

I have a fresh install of Xcode 10.0 beta 6 (10L232m) on macOS Mojave 10.14 beta (18A353d).

When I go into Xcode -> Preferences -> Components I only see iOS 8.x through 11.x, the like for tvOS, and watchOS 2.x - 4.x.

Everything I have read makes me think I should see iOS 12.x runtime simulators listed there as an option to download and install.

Should they be there? If not, how can the runtimes be installed? I didn't see any info on this in my searching so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS 12 Simulator is **preinstalled** with Xcode 10. It's not in the Components list because it cannot be uninstalled.

Try to run an app in the simulator and see it for yourself.